# Python PyQt how to set environment variable for QProcess?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, environment-variables

I'm trying to set an environment variable in a QT app for a QProcess that's being run.  The code is below.  The environment variable does not appear to be set however when inside the test.  Any suggestions?

```
def runUbootTests(self):
    env = QtCore.QProcessEnvironment.systemEnvironment()
    env.insert("LINUX_ETH_ADDR", "3c:98:bf:00:00:f4")
    self.process.setProcessEnvironment(env)
    self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.readReady)
    self.process.start("make", ("clean", "check_uboot"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.environ?  This modified the environment for the current process (as can be seen in /proc as well).

This new environment should be passed along to any spawned processes as well.

Comment: You can check process environment by viewing /proc/pid/environ on proc aware operating systems to see if the environment variable is even being set properly to determine if the environment parser in the QT process is broken or the environment setter.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does not seem obviously wrong, and works for me.

Here's my test files and output:

*Makefile*:

```
clean:  
    @echo 'SHELL:' $(SHELL)

check_uboot:    
    @echo 'ADDR:' $(LINUX_ETH_ADDR)
```

*test.py*:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)

    def handleButton(self):
        env = QtCore.QProcessEnvironment.systemEnvironment()
        env.insert("LINUX_ETH_ADDR", "3c:98:bf:00:00:f4")
        self.process.setProcessEnvironment(env)
        self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.readReady)
        self.process.start("make", ("clean", "check_uboot"))

    def readReady(self):
        print str(self.process.readAllStandardOutput())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*output*:

```
$ python2 test.py
SHELL: /bin/sh

ADDR: 3c:98:bf:00:00:f4
```